Spring authorization server latest version with PKCE + Angular SPA app 403 forbidden on oauth2/token
Security configuration
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationServer();
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth2/jwks").hasAuthority("SCOPE_keys.write"))
                .securityMatchers(matchers ->
                        matchers.requestMatchers(antMatcher("/oauth2/**"), authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher()))
                .with(authorizationServerConfigurer, (authorizationServer) ->
                        authorizationServer.oidc(Customizer.withDefaults()))    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0

                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),
                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        ))
            // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/error", "/main.css")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                // Form login handles the redirect to the login page from the
                // authorization server filter chain
                .formLogin((login) -> login.loginPage("/login"));

        return http.build();
    }

}

Clients Registration
@Configuration
public class Clients {
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient oidcClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("stomble")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantTypes(types -> {
                    types.add(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE);
                    types.add(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN);
                })
                .redirectUris(redirectUri -> {
                    redirectUri.add("http://localhost:4200/");
                    redirectUri.add("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback");
                    redirectUri.add("http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-renew.html");
                    redirectUri.add("http://localhost:4200/auth-callback");
                })
                .postLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:4200/")
                .scopes(score -> {
                    score.add(OidcScopes.OPENID);
                    score.add(OidcScopes.PROFILE);
                    score.add(OidcScopes.EMAIL);
                })
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder()
                        .requireAuthorizationConsent(false)
                        .requireProofKey(true)
                        .build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(oidcClient);
    }
}

Angular App
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5100/oauth2/token", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"131\", \"Chromium\";v=\"131\", \"Not_A Brand\";v=\"24\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site"
  },
  "referrer": "http://localhost:4200/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauth-callback&code=2y8jZGgxjkicK4kIxDTBfgS7gC7dm6yVDRpgRSL8f_eRCf0qe6zrO67q1S0xzl0DX5HD3quSGeSCRr59hSWQC8D7bfINM-YME4L8CcNAelx1KiKvLk5X6UUwgOQoCLps&code_verifier=0d335bff326449bfbaeeb1cc14ef005fae3ac7af0a6e4a9096c48b23988c8ad2206bae4ee2a64f5a975000b39ef8545f&client_id=stomble",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});

Network response
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:5100/oauth2/token
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
403 Forbidden
Remote Address:
127.0.0.1:5100

Using oidc-client.ts library with below configuration https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts
  openID = {
    authority: 'http://127.0.0.1:5100',
    client_id: 'stomble',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    automaticSilentRenew: false,
    silentRenewUrl: window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-renew.html',
    renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 10,
    autoUserInfo: false,
  };

Authentication server logs
logging.level.org.springframework.security.oauth2=trace

server.port=5100

logs
2024-12-03T22:43:02.952+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (7/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.952+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [Or [Or [Ant [pattern='/oauth2/token', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/introspect', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/revoke', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/device_authorization', POST]], Ant [pattern='/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server', GET], Or [Ant [pattern='/oauth2/authorize', GET], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/authorize', POST]], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/token', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/introspect', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/revoke', POST], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/device_authorization', POST], Or [Ant [pattern='/oauth2/device_verification', GET], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/device_verification', POST]], Or [Ant [pattern='/.well-known/openid-configuration', GET], Or [Ant [pattern='/connect/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/connect/logout', POST]], Or [Ant [pattern='/userinfo', GET], Ant [pattern='/userinfo', POST]]], Ant [pattern='/oauth2/jwks', GET]], org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer$BearerTokenRequestMatcher@691500ab]]]
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcLogoutEndpointFilter (8/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (9/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (10/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (11/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter (12/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter (13/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter (14/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.953+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter (15/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.954+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with JwtClientAssertionAuthenticationProvider (1/20)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.955+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with X509ClientCertificateAuthenticationProvider (2/20)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.955+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with ClientSecretAuthenticationProvider (3/20)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.955+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authenticating request with PublicClientAuthenticationProvider (4/20)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.955+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] s.a.a.PublicClientAuthenticationProvider : Retrieved registered client
2024-12-03T22:43:02.955+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] s.a.a.PublicClientAuthenticationProvider : Validated client authentication parameters
2024-12-03T22:43:02.955+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.o.s.a.a.CodeVerifierAuthenticator  : Retrieved authorization with authorization code
2024-12-03T22:43:02.956+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.o.s.a.a.CodeVerifierAuthenticator  : Validated code verifier parameters
2024-12-03T22:43:02.956+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.o.s.a.a.CodeVerifierAuthenticator  : Authenticated code verifier
2024-12-03T22:43:02.956+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] s.a.a.PublicClientAuthenticationProvider : Authenticated public client
2024-12-03T22:43:02.956+11:00 DEBUG 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.a.w.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder authentication to OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter (16/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Did not process request since did not find bearer token
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (17/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (18/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (19/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (20/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (21/26)
2024-12-03T22:43:02.957+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing POST /oauth2/token
2024-12-03T22:43:02.958+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Denying request since did not find matching RequestMatcher
2024-12-03T22:43:02.959+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken [Principal=stomble, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
2024-12-03T22:43:02.959+11:00 TRACE 41205 --- [identity] [nio-5100-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken [Principal=stomble, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]] to access denied handler since access is denied

org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationDeniedException: Access Denied
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:99) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.java:144) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcProviderConfigurationEndpointFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2DeviceVerificationEndpointFilter.java:152) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.java:175) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcLogoutEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcLogoutEndpointFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationServerContextFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:243) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:238) ~[spring-security-config-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:362) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:278) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.33.jar:10.1.33]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

Same issue from Postman as well

To solve the issue I have to add http
.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
.authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth2/token").permitAll()// Allow access to the token endpoint
.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/userinfo").permitAll() but the question is is this is valid in the context of security

@SteveRiesenberg I have pasted as much as I can using logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace

You are receiving an AccessDeniedException due to authorization failure. The default is denyAll(), and you do not have a default rule to override it. Add .anyRequest().authenticated() to your authorizeHttpRequests() to fix this problem.

@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
throws Exception {
http
.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
.requestMatchers("/login", "/error", "/main.css")
.permitAll()
.anyRequest()
.authenticated()
)
.formLogin((login) -> login.loginPage("/login"));
return http.build();
} This code is already present.

Adding this code works- .requestMatchers("/oauth2/token", "/userinfo").permitAll(). However question is that, does this required to be added

.anyRequest().authenticated() is already in the code, but it is not working

Let me type this again since you added a comment at the same time:
No, it is not required nor should it be added. The code you have in the question above is .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth2/jwks").hasAuthority("SCOPE_keys.write")) so when you say "This code is already present." I have no idea what you mean. You seem to be talking about the 2nd filter chain, but I'm referring to the first one which is clearly missing the line of code I suggest.
